# groovycastexception from String to Map in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I am implementing a project in ready api using Groovy.
I created a Groovy script file with the following structure.

```
def templateValue = JsonOutput.toJson('''
{
  "generationTime": null,
  "house": {

    "property": "$property",
    "state": "$state",
    "county": "$county",
    "calls": [
      {
        "first": "$first",
        "second": "$second",
        "third": "third Week"
      }
    ],
    "action": "$action"
  }
}''')
def binding = ["property" : "Villa", "state" : "MA", "county" : "MIDDLE", "first" : "123", "second" : "4565", "action" : "Update"]
def engine = new groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine()
def template = engine.createTemplate(templateValue).make(binding)
log.info template.toString()

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
Map expectedOutput = jsonSlurper.parseText(template.toString())
log.info expectedOutput["property"]
```

I need to get the node values from the json and later remove a particular node from the json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `JsonOutput.toJson` at the top

Try this:

```
def templateValue = '''
{
  "generationTime": null,
  "house": {

    "property": "$property",
    "state": "$state",
    "county": "$county",
    "calls": [
      {
        "first": "$first",
        "second": "$second",
        "third": "third Week"
      }
    ],
    "action": "$action"
  }
}'''
def binding = ["property" : "Villa", "state" : "MA", "county" : "MIDDLE", "first" : "123", "second" : "4565", "action" : "Update"]
def engine = new groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine()
def template = engine.createTemplate(templateValue).make(binding)

def jsonSlurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
Map expectedOutput = jsonSlurper.parseText(template.toString())
println expectedOutput.house.property
```

Comment: thanks. Quick question. How can I remove a node from this JSOn. Say, I want to take out "calls" array from the json.

Comment: got it. expectedOutput.house.remove("calls") works fine to remove the node